# Url link breaks once only

Tags: bibliographies, urls

I have a very long url to show in the references, I am using BibTex and the package url, but I still the url breaks once and not twice as it should.[image]

Comment: Use package `xurl` instead of `url`. Please see that is a relative new package, you need an up-to-date tex distribution!  If that does not help show us please the complete bib entry you used and the tex code you used to build the bibliography. Make sure it is compilable!

Comment: Welcome...Please provide a MWE of what you tried...may be the tags \usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}\usepackage{breakurl} helps you....

Comment: Used xurl, worked! Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Use `xurl` package.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.bib}
@online{savitsky1976procedures,
    title={Procedures for hydrodynamic evaluation of planing hulls in smooth and rough water},
    author={Savitsky, Daniel and Brown, P Ward},
    journal={Marine Technology},
    volume={13},
    number={4},
    pages={381--400},
    year={1976},
    url={https://www.scribd.com/document/380272322/Savitsky-Brown-1976-Procedures-for-Hydrodynamic-Evaluation-of-Planing-Hulls-in-Smooth-Rough-Water-pdf}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}

\cite{savitsky1976procedures}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```